# Query slowdown when joining small table

Tags: sql-server, performance

I've hit a strange problem. I have a query which uses 4 tables (sorry for Latvian names):

- KL_PrecesIzejvielas: 20 rows
- Parvietots_details: 27897 rows
- Razots: 282 rows
- KL_Simple: 25 rows

Tables have only clustered index (primary key), no other indexes.

I'm executing a query:

```
SELECT  KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS AS PreceNosauk ,
        COUNT(*) AS RazosanuSkaits ,
        SUM(SKAITS) AS Kopskaits ,
        Mervienibas.APRAKSTS AS Mervieniba
FROM    KL_Simple AS Mervienibas
        INNER JOIN ( KL_PrecesIzejvielas
                     INNER JOIN ( Parvietots_details
                                  INNER JOIN Razots ON Parvietots_details.ID_PARVIETOTS_MASTER = Razots.ID_PRECES_IEKS_KUST_ID
                                ) ON KL_PrecesIzejvielas.ID = Parvietots_details.ID_PRECE_IZEJVIELA
                   ) ON Mervienibas.ID = KL_PrecesIzejvielas.DEFAULT_MERVIENIBA
WHERE   Razots.ID_ATBILDPERSONA = 27
        AND Razots.DATUMSLAIKS >= ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            DATUMS
                                    FROM    LoginHistory
                                    WHERE   ID_USER = 27
                                    ORDER BY DATUMS DESC
                                  )
GROUP BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS ,
        Mervienibas.APRAKSTS
ORDER BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS ,
        Mervienibas.APRAKSTS
```

Here is the execution plan:
[image: exec plan]
[Link to bigger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ8d6.png)

The query takes 6 seconds to process! Execution plan shows that the biggest work is done when joining the big Parvietots_details table to KL_PrecesIzejvielas and it is done BEFORE applying filter on "Razots". This seems wrong.

The strange thing is, if I only take away the small 25-row table KL_Simple/Mervienibas execution time now is only 126 milliseconds. The big table is now joined AFTER applying filter on "Razots" and I think this is what makes the difference (?)

```
SELECT  KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS AS PreceNosauk ,
        COUNT(*) AS RazosanuSkaits ,
        SUM(SKAITS) AS Kopskaits
FROM    KL_PrecesIzejvielas
        INNER JOIN ( Parvietots_details
                     INNER JOIN Razots ON Parvietots_details.ID_PARVIETOTS_MASTER = Razots.ID_PRECES_IEKS_KUST_ID
                   ) ON KL_PrecesIzejvielas.ID = Parvietots_details.ID_PRECE_IZEJVIELA
WHERE   Razots.ID_ATBILDPERSONA = 27
        AND Razots.DATUMSLAIKS >= ( SELECT TOP 1
                                            DATUMS
                                    FROM    LoginHistory
                                    WHERE   ID_USER = 27
                                    ORDER BY DATUMS DESC
                                  )
GROUP BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS
ORDER BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS
```

[image: exec plan]
[Link to bigger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyfJS.png)

What is the cause of the slowdown? Should I rewrite my query? Why query processor chooses such a plan?

I also tried dropping statistics, but there was no improvement.

EDIT:
Here are execution plan XMLs:
[slow query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/68wpt5g9bl6p8sd/Execution%20plan%20slow.xml)
[fast query](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kxmmofbrcfflo8/Execution%20plan%20fast.xml)

Comment: What is this, a screen shot for ants?

Comment: use the `explain` command

Comment: I must sound dumb, but how do you link inserted image to full size image? I thought it will be done automatically... Now reading help, but can't figure it out.  Added a link below images for now.

Comment: added execution plan XML-s to question

Comment: I will point out that in general you should have indexes on the FK fields as well as the PKs, they are not created automatically and joins are much faster when both sides of the join are able to use an index.

Comment: WHy on earth did you do nested joins? In general they are hard to support and I have never yet seen a case when they were needed or even clear as to intent.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to read the screenshot/SQL because of the size/language. It looks as if they way you are structuring your JOIN to KL_Simple means that the rest of the query is being repeated for every row in KL_Simple.

Comment: it's a simple join, same as 3 others, why is it handled differently? I also tried joining with another table with the same 25 rows and now it works immediately. Scratching my head...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the order of execution of **where** clause and **inner join** does make any difference in the query performance.

The only reason why second query is performing better is you have removed an additional table from the join list. Still you can confirm the fact by executing the following query. In this I've separated the query with where clause in a CTE and then using it in join.

```
with Razots_CTE(ID_ATBILDPERSONA,DATUMSLAIKS,ID_PRECES_IEKS_KUST_ID)as
(select ID_ATBILDPERSONA,DATUMSLAIKS,ID_PRECES_IEKS_KUST_ID from Razots WHERE Razots.ID_ATBILDPERSONA=27 
AND Razots.DATUMSLAIKS >= (SELECT TOP 1 DATUMS FROM LoginHistory WHERE ID_USER=27 ) )

SELECT KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS AS PreceNosauk, 
Count(*) AS RazosanuSkaits, 
SUM(SKAITS) AS Kopskaits
FROM KL_PrecesIzejvielas INNER JOIN 
(Parvietots_details INNER JOIN 
Razots_CTE Razots
ON Parvietots_details.ID_PARVIETOTS_MASTER=Razots.ID_PRECES_IEKS_KUST_ID) 
ON KL_PrecesIzejvielas.ID=Parvietots_details.ID_PRECE_IZEJVIELA
GROUP BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS
ORDER BY KL_PrecesIzejvielas.APRAKSTS
```

Comment: Tried rewriting with CTE and results are the same - first one takes 6 seconds, other works immediately. I also tried joining with another table instead of KL_Simple (with the same 25 rows) and then it also works immediately. So the problem is how KL_Simple is handled. Will post more information tomorrow.

Comment: I was thinking that you will mark my answer as the final answer :)